# No comment highlighting for long comment at end of file

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I made a syntax file with among others a comment region.

It should work like the "c" syntax. Starting with `/*` and ending with `*/`.

Syntax:

```
if exists("dbquery_fold")
    syn region dbqueryComment start="/\*" end="\*/" contains=... extend fold
else
    syn region dbqueryComment start="/\*" end="\*/" contains=... extend
endif
```

On the whole it works.
If I scroll down, either with <kbd>j</kbd> or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> the whole comment is colorized correct.
On `:let dbquery_fold=1` I can fold it.

**Problems:**

I have a very long comment e.g. at the end of a file.

1. I press <kbd>G</kbd> to go to end of file.
   => The comment is not Identified. The text is colored with normal syntax colors.
2. If I scroll to the end <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and then back, no matter how
   => Not all lines are colored as comment. At first all lines are correct and then one line is colored and 6 not. Or 3 are colored and some not.

**How can I tell vim to show it all as comment?**

The file looks like:

```
Line 1  
...  
Line 120  
/*  
Line 122  
...  
Line 922  
*/
```

Comment: `:syn sync ccomment` should probably fix it, otherwise `:syn sync fromstart`; see `:help syn-sync`. There's some more subtleties involved that should be in a good (full) answer though.

Comment: @MartinTournoij - `syn sync fromstart` and `syn sync fromstart` works! And it seems fast enough. I think you should set your comment as answere. Thanks!